# Selecting special tuples from a big list, and dealing with memory limitations

Tags: combinatorics

OK, I'm working on some music theory stuff since that's my hobby. This is what I want to do:

```
deltas = Tuples[{3, 4, 5, -9, -8, -7}, 11]; (* Generate every possible permutation of a minor third, major third, a perfect forth, and their inversions, 11 intervals long*)

musicMod[n_] := Which[n > 0, Mod[n, 12], n < 0, Mod[n, -12], n == 0, 0]; (*This is useful to define for the next function *)

candidates = Table[musicMod /@ Accumulate[Prepend[deltas[[i]], 0]], {i, 1, 
Length[deltas]}]; (* This collects the deltas into sequences of 12 notes, that have the deltas as intervals between them*)

tonerows = Select[candidates, CountDistinct[Mod[#, 12]] == 12 &] (* Finally just select the sequences that have one instance of each pitch class (eg <5,-7>) once *)
```

The problem is I get a memory allocation error in the first line when I try to generate my tuples. I know it's a lot of tuples, 6^11 = 362,797,056, but that's not a ridiculous amount. My computer has 16GB=16,000,000,000 of RAM, so shouldn't it be able to handle it?

Anyway, since I'm just going to end up selecting a small amount of the generated tuples anyway, is there a more efficient way to do it?

(For the musically astute among you, what I'm trying to do is generate a comprehensive list of tone rows made just from minor 3rds, major 3rds, and perfect 4ths, but treating their inversions somewhat distinctly.*)

Edit: Code fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: One of your tuples occupies 184 bytes on my system, so your set of $6^{11}$ tuples would require more than 62 GB of memory. Your system does not even come close to that. For the second part of your question, that's a harder question. Can you specify your selection conditions in mathematical terms? it may be possible to generate the set directly, rather than construct all tuples then filter them.

Comment: Your code doesn't work even when you reduce the number of `Tuples`. I am confused by your definition of `musicMod` as a function of one variable, but then your usage in `candidates` suggests that it should take two inputs. Also, something seems wrong with the `CountDistinct` impression. Can you check the code and make sure that it works when you use fewer tuples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My laptop has only 16 GB of RAM but still manages to produce the list `deltas` within about 24 seconds with a lot of memory compression and swapping.

But for manipulating the $i$-th element, it is not necessary to have all elements in memory. You can directly access the $i$-th tuple of length $n$ with values from `list` with the following function.

```
ithTuple[list_, n_, i_Integer] := list[[1 + IntegerDigits[i - 1, Length[list], n]]];
```

Here is also a small test

```
n = 6;
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 4];
a = ithTuple[list, n, #] & /@ Range[Length[list]^n];
b = Tuples[list, n];
a == b
```

> True